# Struggling with recursive function, what am I doing wrong

Tags: python, recursion

I'm fairly new to python and understand that recursion is an important concept to grasp. I've been dabbling with various scripts to exercise my knowledge and have come up with the following script to  simulate a lottery draw, where you simply draw six from 49 numbers and compare them with another six to see if you've won. I'm struggling though with the recursive function taking the value of another function.

I'm sure it's going to be straightforwardish, but cannot fathom it myself.

Here's my code so far:

```
from random import randint

def drawSix():
    six = []
    while len(six) < 6:
        a = randint(1,49)   
        if a not in six:
            six.append(a)
    return sorted(six)

def lottery(draw,ticket):
    if draw == ticket:
        return 'win'
    return lottery(drawSix(),drawSix())
```

I call the function with lottery(drawSix(),drawSix())

and get the following recursively.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    lottery(drawSix(),drawSix())
  File "/Users/johnhopkins/Desktop/lottery.py", line 14, in lottery
    return lottery(drawSix(),drawSix())
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I keep getting a recursive error see edit in original post

Comment: @hivert look at the very last line....

Comment: Where is a initial call to `lottery` function?

Comment: That isn't really a recursive function. You have implemented a `while` loop by calling the same function again and again, until either the condition is met or the stack overflows. And the latter is more probable since the odds of guessing 6 out of 49 is somewhere around 1:14 million.

Comment: what is the value of ticket when you call the function ?

Comment: Ah understood! :) Facepalm!

Comment: The probability that `draw == ticket` is 1/(49^6) which is a really small probablility. Most of the time you will run out if stack space etc way before that while you are doing recursion. Why are you doing this anyway when the _eventual_ result is going to be `win` anyway!

Comment: Just experimenting with python. I would have eventually implemented a count to see how many tickets I would have to buy to win. Haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def lottery(draw,ticket):
    if draw == ticket:
        return 'win'
    return lottery(drawSix(),drawSix())
```

The odds of you actually generating two identical tickets are quite large, well over 1000 which is the maximum stack size of Python.

You need to either do this iteratively to avoid blowing your stack.

```
def lottery(draw,ticket):
    while draw != ticket:
        draw, ticket = drawSix(), drawSix()
    return "win"
```

Note this has a very ugly `O(n)` of `O(inf)` you could end up running this forever if you were unlucky and still not finding a winning pair

Comment: I'll not be buying a lottery ticket in a hurry! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question has has been answered, but I would suggest changing your `drawSix` function. As it is now, it could technically run forever. `random` has a `sample` method to generate unique numbers.

```
def drawSix():
    return sorted(random.sample(range(1, 50), 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the `lottery` function will keep on calling itself, each time putting a new version of itself onto the call stack, going deeper and deeper into itself until there are two matching numbers.

This can take a long time, and Python will eventually say "oi! stop it!" and crash.

Some programming languages have a feature called 'tail call optimisation', which means if you try to `return` the result of the same function, instead of making a *new* call to the function inside the current one, it simply replaces itself in the stack.

Python doesn't do that.

```
def lottery():
    while (drawSix() != drawSix()):
        continue
    return 'win!'
```

will have the same effect as your recursive version, but won't die with recursion errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have not made any programming mistakes. However, the probility of winning the lottery is very small, so you need to generate a lot. Easy recursion add something to the stack.

Number of lotto tickets can be found by the formula for combinations with repetition:

```
(49+6-1)! / (6! * (49-1)!) = 25827165
```

This is a lot... Decrease the number 6 or 49, add some debugging lines and you'll see that the code works fine!